# xamarin forms app dont pull data from azure easy tables

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I followed this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/) to create backend app for may xamarin forms app, I can save some data to easy table but i can't retrieve existing data from azure table to mobile, i get  Push operation has failed when pull data when trying to pull data.

Comment: the tables you are pulling, actually have UpdatedAt value ?

Comment: yes they have UpdatedAt value.

Answer (score 0):

> I can save some data to easy table but i can't retrieve existing data from azure table to mobile, i get Push operation has failed when pull data when trying to pull data.

As [How offline synchronization works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync#how-sync-works) states about **Implicit Pushes**:

> If a pull is executed against a table that has pending local updates, the pull first executes a `push()` on the sync context. This push helps minimize conflicts between changes that are already queued and new data from the server.

For retrieving the detailed error when executing the pull operation, you could try to use fiddler to capture the network traces to narrow down this issue. Moreover, you may need to handle the conflict (catch the `MobileServicePushFailedException`) for the push operation. Details you could follow adrian hall's book about [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution).

For a simple way, I would recommend you download the Xamarin.Forms sample project under "Development > Quickstart" blade of your mobile app on Azure Portal, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started#download-and-run-the-xamarinforms-solution). Moreover, you could also follow [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/) tutorial to get started with Azure Mobile Apps by using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Thanks for reply Bruce,now i can retrieve data but I can't caching them for offline use,how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you are using the quickstart solution, you need to uncomment the `#define OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED` directive under `TodoItemManager.cs`. For detailed instruction, you could follow [Enable offline sync for your Xamarin.Forms mobile app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data).